# Multiple response question with copied observations

Tags: logistic, survey

For an analysis with the answers of a multiple response question submitted by respondents as the dependent variable, I was thinking of using duplicate observations. 
So e.g. if a respondent submitted 2 answers, I would copy the independent variables of that observation for both the first and second answer.

I'm rather skeptical with this approach and would like to ask what the consequences are if I would do this. It seems that it would dilute the underlying patterns, could this be what is happening?

Thanks in advance

Comment: To clarify: were your respondents surveyed only once, but were allowed to pick multiple answers from the choices in the questionnaire?  Can you give us more information about the research question you are trying to answer, e.g. what's the outcome of interest and what are some of the predictors of interest?